GStreamer tool mp4 aac streaming via rtp
I built an rtp sender that should transmit h264 video and aac audio, but it gives an error.
No sink-element named "(null)" - omitting link
gst-launch-1.0 -e -vv v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! queue ! openh264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! mp40. autoaudiosrc ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_aac  !  aacparse ! mp40. mp4mux name = mp4 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host = 127.0.0.1 port = 5003

How could I correct it?

Could you try this pipe?
gst-launch-1.0 -e -vv v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! queue ! openh264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! mux. autoaudiosrc ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_aac  !  aacparse ! queue ! mux. mpegtsmux name=mux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5003


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
